# Make tabs appear vertically on the side when using p:tabMenu?

Tags: primefaces

I am `p:tabMenu` to show menu items, but they all are horizontally ordered but now client demands vertically. How to make tabs appear vertically on the side when using `p:tabMenu`?

Comment: Did you actually look at any Showcase? Documentation?  Your question lacks a lot of effort. Sorry, direct downvote from me.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry tabMenu and not tab... `p:tabMenu` does not have this functionality afaik. Removed my previous comment. But please next time add a little more info. Version info and what you investigated and e.g. that the plan tabView does have this.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabmenu-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabmenu-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabmenu-nav li a { display:block; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabmenu-nav li.ui-state-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Maybe add a feature request in the github issuelist. But please add a little text to this answer.

Comment: There is actually a feature request for this: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/76